# Find the first match between 2 objects

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects

```
const obj1 = {
    item1: {
        name: '1'
    },
    item2: {
        name: '2'
    }
}

const obj2 = {
    item1: {
        sample: 'sample1'
    },
    item2: {
        sample: 'sample2'
    }
}
```

How can I loop over the second object `obj2`, find the first match against object `obj1` and return it?

In above example, I should return

```
{
    item1: {
        name: '1'
    }
}
```

since `item1` is the first match between the 2 objects and I want what's inside obj1.

Tried the following:

```
const keys = obj2 && Object.keys(obj2);

const output = () => {
    if (keys) {
        const finalResponse = keys.map(key => {
          if (obj1[key]) return obj1[key];
          return undefined;
        });
        return finalResponse
    }
    return null
}
```

But ends up getting 2 matches when I only want the first time it matches.

Is there a cleaner way to do this.

Fine to loop over obj1 or obj2 as long as I can return the match in obj1.

Comment: There is no concept of "first match" in an object.  Objects are not ordered.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I meant as long as there is a match I am fine. They are all unique so if there is a match, can only be one.

Comment: your output function doesnt return anything

Comment: @ChrisLi Thanks fixed that above. Now end up with 2 matches when I was only looking to stop with first match.

Comment: @karvai You already have the solution, you can save the key that was matched in a variable when the match exists.

Comment: @karvai for what you want to achieve, just use a for loop and return when you find a match, instead of array.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the solution, you can save the key that was matched in a variable when the match exists.

```
const keys = obj2 && Object.keys(obj2);
let keyMatched = '';
const output = () => {
    if (keys) {
        const finalResponse = keys.map(key => {
          if (obj1[key] && !keyMatched) {   // Check for first match  
              keyMatched = key;   // Save the first match
              return obj1[key];
          }
          return undefined;
        });
        return finalResponse
    }
    return null
}
```

### Demo run

```js
const obj1 = {
  item1: {
      name: '1'
  },
  item2: {
      name: '2'
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  item1: {
      sample: 'sample1'
  },
  item2: {
      sample: 'sample2'
  }
}
const keys = obj2 && Object.keys(obj2);
let keyMatched = '';
const output = () => {
    if (keys) {
        const finalResponse = keys.map(key => {
          if (obj1[key] && !keyMatched) {   // Check for first match  
              keyMatched = key;   // Save the first match
              return obj1[key];
          }
          return undefined;
        });
        return finalResponse
    }
    return null
}
output();
const newObj = {
    [keyMatched]: obj1[keyMatched]
}
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: @karvai, the time complexity for this solution is `O(n^2)`, which is too much for the solution. However, below mentioned solution have lesser time complexity than this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Object.keys(obj1).find(prop=>obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop));
```

You can also use result to build Objekt

```
var resObj = {[result]:obj1[result]};
```

```js
const obj1 = {
  item1: {name: '1'},
  item2: {name: '2'}
}
const obj2 = {
  item1: {sample: 'sample1'},
  item2: {sample: 'sample2'}
}
var result = Object.keys(obj1).find(prop=>obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop));
var resObj = {[result]:obj1[result]};
console.log(resObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

With this, find the `obj1` keys that are in `obj2`...

```
const object2keys = new Set(Object.keys(obj2));
const intersection = Object.keys(obj1).filter(key => object2keys.has(key));
```

With this, use the first (arbitrary) intersecting key to build an object with the matching key/value pair from `obj1`...

```
const match = intersection.length ? intersection[0] : null;
const result = match ? { [match] : obj1[match] } : {}
```

Demo...

```js
const obj1 = {
  item1: {
    name: '1'
  },
  item2: {
    name: '2'
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  item1: {
    sample: 'sample1'
  },
  item2: {
    sample: 'sample2'
  }
}

const object2keys = new Set(Object.keys(obj2));
const intersection = Object.keys(obj1).filter(key => object2keys.has(key));
const match = intersection.length ? intersection[0] : null;
const result = match ? { [match] : obj1[match] } : {}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1 = {
  item1: {
    name: '1'
  },
  item2: {
    name: '2'
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  item1: {
    sample: 'sample1'
  },
  item2: {
    sample: 'sample2'
  }
}

const obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1)
const obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2)


let match = null;

obj2Keys.every((key) => {
  if (obj1Keys.includes(key)) {
    match = obj1[key]
    return false
  }
  return true
})

console.log(match)
```

Comment: Could I return obj1[key] itself or false/true are there to break out on first match?

Comment: No, you need to return true or false for `every` function. If it solves your problem please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I mean .. Too many iterations for so simple task

Comment: @VitLit retruing false will stop the loop and we will get first matching item. So it's not too many interation.

Comment: @VitLit i guess your answer and my answer have same time complexity.